# How to fix redux dev tools?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I used to use Redux-Logger before and everything was fine, but when I want to use Redux-dev-Tools and I want to add this code:
‍‍

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

it does not work and gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you read the redux dev tools [documentation](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#installation). And I think your problem is not using the compose function.

Please edit your code as written below:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default store;
```

Or you can use the function inside the package by installing the Redax-dev-Tools package:

> npm install redux-devtools-extension

Or if you use yarn:

> yarn add redux-devtools-extension

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
));
```